# How do I compute the following integral:$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{dx}{x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How do I compute the following integral: $\int_{1}^{2} \frac{dx}{x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}}$. I really don't know where to start. I think I have to use Euler's substitution method but I'm not sure how.

**Attempt at solving the problem**

$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{dx}{x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}}$ = $\int_{1}^{2} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^+1}-x)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}dx$ = $\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{x^2+1}dx$ - $\int_{1}^{2} x dx$ = $\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{x^2+1}dx$ - $\frac{3}{2}$

$(arsin x)' = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ therefore $\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{x^2+1}dx$ = $arsin(2) - arsin(1)$

Therefore

$\int_{1}^{2} \frac{dx}{x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}}$ = $arsin(2) - arsin(1) - 3/2$

Comment: $x = \cosh(z)$ may work fine

Comment: @1over137: No, it is $\cosh^2u−\sinh^2u=1$, so only $x=\sinhu$ will work as intended. -- celes: $(\arcsin x)'=\frac1{\sqrt{1−x^2}}$, which is why your attempt fails. However, $(Arsinhx)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$, which could then followed to the result.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

Let $x$ be the hyperbolic sine of $t$, so that $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is the cosine. Then

$$\int \frac{dx}{x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\int\frac{\cosh(t)}{e^t}dt=\int\frac{1+e^{-2t}}2dt=\frac{2t-e^{-2t}}4.$$

---

Another interesting option is $x=t-\dfrac1t$, so that $\sqrt{x^2+1}=t+\dfrac1t$.

$$\int \frac{dx}{x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\int\frac{1+\frac1{t^2}}{2t}dt=\frac12\ln(t)-\frac1{4t^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)=?$$

Or

choose  $x=\tan y$

Comment: why do I have to set$ x = tan y$?

Comment: @celes, Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

Rationalize denominator as follows $$\int_1^2\frac{dx}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$=\int_1^2\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)dx}{(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)}$$
$$=\int_1^2\frac{(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)dx}{x^2+1-x^2}$$
$$=\int_1^2(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)dx$$
using product-rule for the first integral, one should get,
$$=\left[\frac{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+1}|-\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_1^2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)=1$$

so

$$=\int\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x \right)dx=\int \sqrt{x^2+1}dx-\int xdx$$

Set $x=\tan t$ and $dx=\sec^2tdt$ so $\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sqrt{\tan^2 t+1}=\sec t$ and $t=\arctan x$

$$=\int\sec^3 t dt-\int xdx=\dots$$

Now you can use the reduction formula, I will let you  finish.

Comment: Why did you make the decision of setting x=tan t?

Comment: @celes never heard about integration by substitution?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Area sinus hyperbolicus is the solution of
$$
x=\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}\iff (e^y)^2-2e^yx-1\iff e^y=x\pm \sqrt{1+x^2}
$$
so that
$$
\sinh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})
$$
which should reinforce the idea that substituting $x=\sinh(u)$ is a sensible choice.